# Decouple dictionary that contains a list as a value for a particular key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a dict in Python that follows this structure:

```py
dict_a = {"a": [1,2,3]}
```

I want to produce an output to '*decouple*' `dict_a` in a list of 3 separate dicts like

```py
>>> [{"a": 1}, {"a": 2}, {"a": 3}]
```

What I have now is:

```py
dict_a = {"a": [1,2,3]}
result = []

for key, values in dict_a.items():
    for value in values:
        result.append({key: value})

print(result)
>>> [{"a": 1}, {"a": 2}, {"a": 3}]
```

Is there any way to achieve this or a similar 'decoupling' behavior with list comprehension or a `dict` related method?

Comment: if `dict_a` has several items, they would all be split into a different `dict`. Is that desired?  Or would you like to bundle together all `values[0]` into `results[0]`, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the for loops are quite pythonic and readable, the same can be achieved with comprehensions:

```py
dict_a = {"a": [1,2,3]}
result = [{k: v} for k, vs in dict_a.items() for v in vs]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Just what I needed, thanks!